# Logical constraints in gurobi

Tags: constraints, logical-operators, gurobi

I have a few gurobi variables a[i], b[i],c[i] (for i in 0 to some number), and I would like to add the constraint

```
for i in range(0, number):
   m.addConstr(a[i]==b[i] if c[i]==1)
```

According to the gurobi website, this is possible, but when I try to implement it (in python), I keep getting an invalid syntax error because of the if.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I should mention that I don't want to use the big M method if possible

Answer (score 3):

If c[i] is a binary variable, the if-then-logic can be achieved with indicator constraints:

```
for i in range(0, number):
    m.addGenConstrIndicator(c[i], 1, a[i] == b[i])
```

Or you can use the overloaded form:

```
for i in range(0, number):
    m.addConstr((c[i] == 1) >> (a[i] == b[i]))
```

See [here](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/py_model_addgenconstrindic.html) for further details and examples.

Comment: This assumes that c[i] is a binary decision variable

Answer (score -1):

Here your running `for` loop which will create multiple constraints, so try to use below code which uses `addConstrs()` method.

```
m.addConstrs((a[i]==b[i] for i in range(number) if c[i]==1), name = "c")
```